# Is it normal docker daemon kill/restart containers on a short time span?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We started to monitor docker events in our k8s cluster and noticed that are a lot of `Kill/Die/Stop/Destroy` for various containers in a short time period.

Is that normal? (I assume it's not)

Aparently is not a capacity problem:

```
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:19:30 -0300   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 14:02:37 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:19:30 -0300   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 14:02:37 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:19:30 -0300   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 14:02:37 -0300   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:19:30 -0300   Fri, 11 May 2018 16:37:48 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:19:30 -0300   Tue, 14 Aug 2018 14:02:37 -0300   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
```

All Pods shows status "Running"

Any tips on how debug it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the docker container status as following commands on the node hosts where runs pods on.

```
docker inspect <container id>
```

More option is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

And events logs and journal logs are helpful to debug.

```
kubectl get events

journalctl --no-pager
```

Comment: So, it turns out that everytime I change Pod/Deploy annotations the container is killed.

Comment: Yes, that’s normal.